# removing multiple occurences of alphabets in a word

Tags: java, string

I want to remove multiple occurrences of a character **using a single array**.
Say the word entered is "APPLE" then the output should be "APLE".
Similarly for "Soccer" it should be "Socer".

Please help.

Comment: ok. Where is your try?

Comment: Help with what? You've only introduced your problem. It's like saying: "I'm Maroun, please help"

Comment: Your result array must be shorter than source. In java it is impossible to change array length.

Comment: I was looking specifically for the logic i.e what could be the approach to the problem. Like say for the word "APPLE" if i shift the index to the left once i found any repeated character, and it would be like "APLEE" after the final iteration . Now how to remove/drop the last index of the array so as to make it "APLE"..

Comment: There are lots of ways to solve this.  I expect your interviewer was more interested in >>how you approached the problem<< than in the specific solution.  Also ... he / she would want to know if you have a clear understanding of how Java arrays work; e.g. that you can't make an existing array shorter or longer.

Answer (score 3):

I won't do your homework, but here are some hints:

- Use a "read index" and a "write index"
- Whenever you read a character (from the read index), you write the character (to the write index) only if it has not been seen before.

Comment: Thanks...actually i face the question during an interview where the interviewer is looking just for the logic itself. And I tried for a couple of minute and pass the question :(..... Can you please suggest an online resource for exploring the solution

Comment: Try implementing the algorithm I've described, and post a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: *"Can you please suggest an online resource for exploring the solution"* - The best resource is an editor, java / javac ... and trying to solve it yourself.